# How To Get The Tax Rate From A Product

Tags: magento2, product, tax

I am looking to get the tax rate value from a product (not quote item) in a plugin, which fires on the **beforeAddProduct()** method.

Currently I have the following in my plugin code:

```
$taxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();
```

this returns an id such as `2` for example.

I attempt to use this value using the `Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface` **getCalculatedRate()** method:

```
$productTaxRate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($taxClassid);
```

but then this just returns a `0` which is incorrect as in the admin, the Tax Class is set to `A_GEN_STANDARD` which is set to a rate of **20%**

Surely there must be a simple to get the tax rate value from a product?

Just to confirm, this is for a product, not a quote item :)

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can get tax rate by:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$taxCalculation = $objectManager->create( 'Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate' )->load( <tax_rate_id> , 'tax_calculation_rate_id' );

$rate = $taxCalculation->getRate();
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad. I'd like to avoid using the load() method where possible, as this is deprecated. I did try this approach also though but it returned a null value.
In the admin for the particular product, the tax class is set to A_GEN_STANDARD for 20%

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(        
    \Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation $taxCalculation,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->taxCalculation = $taxCalculation;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
} 
  Public function getTaxPercentage(){
      $productTaxClassId = $product->getTaxClassId();
      $defaultCustomerTaxClassId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('tax/classes/default_customer_tax_class');
      $store      = $this->_storeManager->getStore(); 
      $request = $this->taxCalculation->getRateRequest(null, null, null, $store);
      $taxRate = $this->taxCalculation->getRate($request->setProductClassId($productTaxClassId))
}
```

Comment: Hi @quickshiftin. The problem with this approach, is it's getting the Tax rate from the store config, but what I need is to get the tax rate per product, specified in the Tax Class product attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can get tax rates by using \Magento\Tax\Api\TaxCalculationInterface:

```
    $rate = $this->taxCalculation->getCalculatedRate($productTaxClassId, $customerId, $storeId);
```

Comment: Hi @quickshiftin. Nope that didn't work either. The $customerId and $storeId values are null by default for that method. Regardless I tried plugging those values but still get 0 as the result, which is incorrect.